# Azure Logic App doesn't found my Google sheet where add a single row

Tags: google-sheets, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to create my first logic app and I'm totally blind so sorry if this question should seem silly.
Told that, the logic app should receive an http request with 5 parameters and than copyies these parameters into a Google sheet on my Google Drive.
The problem is that the logic app retrieve a 404 resource not found when is on the add row step!
These were my temptatives:

1. selection of the file by inserting the name manually;
2. selection the file using the button "See the selection" (or something like that I'm traslating the interface from italian to english);
3. add all the url from https to sharing;
4. add only the key of the file;
5. change the privilegies of the file from private to public but using only the 2nd and 3rd case.

Someone can help me to understand where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I found the solution, I didn't specify any sheet so, probably, the logic app didn't know where it should insert the row!

P.S.: It is true also if the spreadsheet has only a sheet (it was my case)